# Quick energy for a dog?

Tags: dogs, diet, exercise

What can you give a dog that needs a quick energy boost when it is running? Similar to how humans drink glucose (and salt?) when running marathon and similar.

Comment: There must be veterinary advice for working/competing dogs; in your place I'd try some search terms related to that. Wild guess: some kind of appropriately balanced meat broth might be fastest to be absorbed while at least resembling a reasonable nutritional profile .

Comment: Dogs don't sweat, so I would assume electrolyte replenishment needs would be significantly different from those of a human.

Comment: @keshlam But they lose water from their tongue/breathing.

Comment: I didn't say absent, just different.